# Reading Pixel Data From JPG Image

Tags: java, image, jpeg

I´m reading a simple jpg image with Java and printing out a 2d array of the pixel data.

If I have the entire image black I get what I expect:
This is the 10x20 black image

[image]

And the result:

```
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

However if I draw a white line on the first row of the image I'm getting 1's in a place I don´t expect:
The other image:

```
-1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1    //Why??
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

This is my code:

```
byte[][]pixels;
BufferedImage image;

public ImageProcessor(File f) throws IOException{
    image = ImageIO.read(f);
    //Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());  // Si es jpg
    pixels = new byte[image.getWidth()][];

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        pixels[x] = new byte[image.getHeight()];

        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            pixels[x][y] = (byte) (image.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }    

}

public void printPixelMatrix(){
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++) {
            System.out.print(" "+pixels[j][i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Java so I'm going on general computer graphics knowledge...

1) Firstly, You might want to set a **type** for your buffered image (ie: 4 byte where you have 1 byte for each component of R + G + B + Alpha). Something like `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

2) I don't get why you try to put the result of `image.getRGB(x, y)` into a byte. From Java docs it seems `getRGB(x, y)` returns an array not a single number and even then, that number would have combined all **A-R-G-B** as one but a byte can only hold one component's value as max amount (up to `255`, but a color `int` could be like `4278254335` spread over 4 bytes).

**suggested solution :** Instead of bytes (and strides?), just scan the pixels and get an `int` of the pixel value. Then print those values. `Black = 0` and also `White = 4278254335`. I think I got the Hex format code okay below, so that should show as : `Black = FF000000` and then `White = FFFFFFFF`.

I think your final code should work something like as shown below. Please fix any mistakes (I put comments so you see what I am trying to do). That should give you the expected colours of the black, or black with white line, in the expected positions :

```
//# load your old one as usual
image = ImageIO.read(f);

//# Create a new bufferdImage with type (will draw old into this) //also consider TYPE_INT_RGB
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

//# Then draw original into new type...
Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
g.dispose(); //needed or not???

//# Doing the For-loop
int imgW = image.getWidth();
int imgH = image.getHeight();
int pixels[][] = new int[imgW][imgH]; //create a 2D array

//# Fill Array : for each [x] pos we read down /column 
//# so that we fill [y] with those pixel values
for (int x = 0; x < imgW; x++) 
{
    //On each X pos we scan all Y pixels in that column 
    for (int y = 0; y < imgH; y++) 
    {
        int col = image.getRGB(x, y);
        pixels[x][y] = col;

        //printPixelARGB( col ); //if you need this format instead of printPixelMatrix
    }
} 

//# To Print output
public void printPixelMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++) 
        {
            //System.out.print(" " + pixels[j][i] + " ");
            int c = pixels[j][i]; //get integer that was stored in the array
            String HexVal = Integer.toHexString( c ) //giveshex value like AARRGGBB
            System.out.print(" " + HexVal + " ");
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }        

}

//# Another helper function to print pixel values
//# print out example blue : argb: 255, 0, 0, 255
public void printPixelARGB(int pixel) 
{
    int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
    int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
    int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
    int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
    System.out.println("ARGB : " + alpha + ", " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have unsigned types, so your "white" pixels, which are the maximum value (`0xff`), are interpreted as negative 1.

Presumably your positive 1s are a compression artifact.

Comment: Is there any way I can remove the positve 1's to get the exact pixel data from the image? Or is the compression thing related to my image Editor?

Comment: @PabloEstrada JPEG is loss based compression algorithm, you could try using a different format, like png

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are getting an artifact from JPEG quantization. JPEG compresses square blocks of pixels, not individual pixels.

See if there is a way to change your quantization tables. If you make them all 1 values, this should go away. Some encoders use "quality" settings for this. Use the highest quality setting.